# Is it save to replace SQLite database

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite, android-file

I've added an option in my application where the user can backup the application to Google Drive.

---

I'm getting the reference to the database like this:

```
File dbFile = new File(context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getAbsolutePath());
```

When I log the above to get the path, this gets returned - `/data/user/0/my.package.name/databases/DatabaseName.DB`

I then create a copy of my database and upload it to Google Drive.

This is working fine.

---

Now, on a different device, I download the database to my application's directory.
After it is saved I move/replace the old database, by doing the following:

```java
try {
    //The database is stored here from Google Drive
    File directoryFile = context.getExternalFilesDir("BackupDB");
    InputStream mInput = new FileInputStream(directoryFile+"/DatabaseName.DB");
    //Path to current database - /data/user/0/my.package.name/databases/DatabaseName.DB
    String outFileName = context.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getAbsolutePath();
    OutputStream mOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] mBuffer = new byte[1024];
    int mLength;
    while ((mLength = mInput.read(mBuffer))>0){
        mOutput.write(mBuffer, 0, mLength);
    }
    mOutput.flush();
    mOutput.close();
    mInput.close();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The above works fine on my device.

---

I've seen some people say that `/data/data/` can only be accessed by rooted devices, but I've also seen a lot of people say that we can override our application's database.

**My Question:**

Is it safe for me to access and override my application database on all android versions? Or are there limitations?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a problem with that since you're accessing directories private to you app data and they are removed once the app is removed, check the table on this page:

[Data and file storage overview](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage)

On the other hand why don't you use Cloud Firestore DB instead of backing your sqlite DB and storing it to google drive then downloading etc..

Just create your DB on [FireBase CoudFirestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore) and secure it with rules, use the API to load your db into the application on any device and store it locally in a [Room DB](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room), use Room as your single source of truth for the app.